# In turbo c++ can a normal recursive function converted as tail-recursive to optimize it?

Tags: c++, recursion, turbo-c++

I'm creating one factorial program in c++ using normal recursion function. I want to convert it to tail recursion to prevent stack overflow if the input value is large. How can I convert my normal recursion to tail recursion?

```
// An example of tail recursive function
void print(int n)
{
   if (n < 0)  return;
   printf(" %d",n);

    // The last executed statement is recursive call
    print(n-1);
 }
```

Comment: have you already read about tail recursion throughly?

Comment: Do consider upgrading from a mid/early-1990's compiler to something more modern. Compilers are free nowadays.

Comment: but c/c++ is our subject in school

Comment: @vivekkumar There's no "turbo" in that subject name. There are plenty of other C compilers as well as C++ compilers. GCC is a popular and widely available choice. clang is a somewhat newer, somewhat less widely available, but still popular choice. Microsoft Visual Studio is another popular choice for Windows. And there are more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've written one sample tail recursion function in c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// tail recursion
unsigned factTR(unsigned int num, unsigned int count)
{
    if (num == 0)  return count;

    return factTR(num-1, num*count);
}

// factTRecurive
unsigned int fact(unsigned int n)
{
    return factTR(n, 1);
}

// calling function
int main()
{
   cout << fact(8);
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This relies on the compiler to optimise your `factTR` to tail recursion. It is written so that it is possible, but a compiler isn't required to do that. In the question, the function is *also* written so that it is possible, but the OP still wanted to rewrite it.